# Retrieving an Invoice as PDF in QuickBooks API V3

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Will retrieving Invoice documents as PDFs be available in QuickBooks API V3? If so, will QuickBooks Desktop be supported as well? In V2 (Intuit Data Services), only QuickBooks Online was supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not available in v3 yet. Currently only in v2. It will be supported eventually but not in the next 6 months. You can of course use v3 and v2 only to save an invoice as pdf if necessary.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: Thanks Jarred. What about PDFs for QB Desktop in V3?

Comment: I was referring to both QBO and QBD.

Comment: Looks like this is possible now. https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1060982-quickbooks-online-api-invoice-pdf-download

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dataService->throwExceptionOnError(true);

    $invoice = $dataService->FindById("Invoice", $invoiceId);

    $filename = "$customerEmail.pdf";

    $pdfData = $dataService->DownloadPDF($invoice, null, true);

    // Send the file to the browser.
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');

    echo $pdfData;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).